# Working principle of the five(5) needle telegraph by Cooke and WheatStone

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction, history, batteries

So I’m studying the history of telecommunications and came across the five (5) needle telegraph by Cooke and WheatStone. I want to replicate it but can’t get a grasp on the working principles.

In a lot of explanations I only see one telegraph. I wonder if the transmitter and receiver have one each and what happens if they both try to send messages at once.
I know electromagnetic induction and battery play a part but I don’t really understand how they play.

Please I need detailed answers on the working principles or you can point me where,I can find answers or the knowledge I need to get to understand it.

Thank you in advance for the helpful answers.

Comment: [This one-hour talk on character encodings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mZBa3sqTrI) discusses the five-wire telegraph in detail. As for duplexing communications on a shared channel, the operators have to take turns; compare with saying “over” to indicate that you’re done speaking into your walkie-talkie and that you’re ready to receive a response.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob, for responding and the great analogy really helped me understand it. I will check out the video right away, Thanks.

Comment: that’s a big ten four, over and out